# how is a website supposed to be OOP if it doesn't need inheritance

Tags: php, oop

i'm trying to make a website, i want it to be OOP but i'm kind of new to it, do i have to have inheritance and polymorphism to be OOP? child classes inherit from the parent class if they need to have common logic, i barely have something in common, if i make a parent class i'll be inheriting some variables and that's it, i won't be using a constructer because every other class has extra different variables to use in the functions, the functions behave very differently, let me show you what i mean:

```
class package{

//some variables

function addToDatabase(Parameters sent from handler page){
//nothing in common so nothing is here }


//other functions with same situation

}


class letter extends functionality{

function addToDatabase(){
//actual logic }

}

class gift extends functionality{

function addToDatabase(){
//actual logic  }

}
```

what i actually implemented

```
class dataEntry{

function addGift(parameters sent from handler page){
 //it's own logic
}

function addLetter(parameters sent from handler page){
 //it's own logic
}

}
```

i call the function needed in the class from a handler page based on what form was submitted, the handler page has a switch statement and does this:

```
case 'package':
//define parameters from the $_POST input

$obj = new package();
$obj->addgift(parameters defined);
```

for me this is much more logical, but the concept of inheritance and polymorphism won't be applied, i need some tips or any comment.

Comment: If you're making the website, it can be whatever you want it to be. Why do you 'need' it to be completely OOP if you yourself have identified that you'll only be using a very small subset of OOP concepts? Granted, it doesn't need to be procedural either - you could use a mix. And you can always change the code later on. What you need depends largely on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i need it to be oop because it's a school project, not for myself sadly :')

Comment: Ahh, that makes things slightly different ;)

Comment: sooo, my design isn't slightly close to OOP right? :') im gonna kms

Comment: OOP provides many features, inheritance is just one of them.

Comment: `do i have to have inheritance and polymorphism to be OOP`...no. Not unless your tutor has told you specifically to use those concepts for this exercise.

Answer (score -2):

it's not **S**OLID solution: you must separate by data layers: data transports like as controllers/middlewares, data structures like as models/components and data storages like as PDO.

- controllers/middlewares pass request data to models/components
- models/components validate passed data and update DB by PDO.

Comment: There's no "must" about it. OP "could" follow SOLID if they want to. It's not a requirement! These types of principles and patterns are all different options that people can use, not mandatory.

Comment: @ADyson English is not my native language, so there may be inaccuracies.